# How do I get a link to a WP page within a loop?

Tags: permalinks

I'm trying to get a link to Page A within a loop on Page B. Normally I would use `<?php echo get_page_link($mypage->ID); ?>` but the loop is causing this to always return a path to the current page.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that if you pass a Post or Page object to the_permalink() or get_page_link() it will override the post object set by the loop whereas passing an ID won't.

In the previous example you would use `<?php echo get_page_link($mypage); ?>` instead.

Source of get_page_link() had the answers: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_link/

Comment: `echo get_permalink($mypage->ID);` will also work.  And looking at the souce, passing an ID via `get_page_link()` should work just fine.